# Missing return statement after catch{throw..} implementation

Tags: android, passwords, keystore

It says missing return statement even tho it has return in `try` block. I do not understand it.
I am trying to make an android app and and also store the login credentials for that app with android `keystore`.
Also if anyone can give me an example of simple `keystore` implementation, that would be great. I found 2 example and they are not very understandable(missing codes) and also hard to implement to my situation.

```
private SecretKey createKey() {
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("Key", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)            //burayı kaldırırsan screen locka gerek kalmaz
                    .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(5)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                    .build());
            return keyGenerator.generateKey();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add also - throws RuntimeException in your method definition.

Comment: @Jay If you throw an exception you don't need to return anything. As he's throwing a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @Jay, Yeah, I missed that one. Thanks for the clarification. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you don't have a return if your `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M` condition isn't met.

```
private SecretKey createKey() {
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // ...
            return keyGenerator.generateKey();
        }
        // add a return here if we're not on >= Android M.
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e);
    }
    // you could also have a return here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, stupid of me. Any advice what to return in try, after if condition? Since I have to return SecretKey, but it has no use if the if statement doesn't meet that condition.

Comment: yes we need to have return within if and else both !

Comment: @redduckto Personally I would move the check for Android version outside of the method. You don't want to run `createKey()` for older devices. If this is in a dialog, you should just not show the dialog to the user. That would mean that anyone who gets to `createKey()` is at least using Android M.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a return statement that is run if your if-statement does not meet the requirements. Right now, you only return something if the SDK is greater than the Build.VERSION_CODES.M.

You could put a return statement after the whole try and catch, because if you return in the try it will leave the method. This means the other return is only run if the build SDK does not meet requirements.

```
private SecretKey createKey() {
try {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("Key", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)            //burayı kaldırırsan screen locka gerek kalmaz
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(5)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    }
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e);
}

// Return here...
```

}

Comment: So what should I return after catch for example?Without breaking the logic in code?

Comment: @redduckto I haven't looked much into the KeyGenerator. But I guess you don't want to use it if the SDK version is not high enough? If not I would try to maybe just create a null keyGenerator to return, together with a errormessage? If not I would just do the code you want for people with not a high enough SDK. Don't know if that helped.

Answer (score 1):

add return statement before the last curly bracket